# TYPO3 / OwlSlider PageSpeed Insights - Unable to optimize due to deffer

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagespeed

I have a TYPO3 Page where i need to get a score above 90.
For this in particular i've already set jQuery, OwlCarousel and the initating script to defer.

However, if i keep the Slider away from loading, i get a 97 Score.
If i keep it, it goes down as far as 71.

"Reduce initial response time of the server" comes around if i load it all defer.
As for my understanding, this happens because it loads the HTML and seperatly the JavaScript.
But that will make the Slider load later ofc. because the document gets first loaded.

But if i will load jQuery, OwlCarousel and the init-script without defer the score also will get to 74.

I dont see a solution here, any tipps?

```
var slider = '.slider-owl-268';
var tnav = true;
var amount = 1;
var dautoplay = false;
amount = parseInt(amount);
var tdots = true;

    $(slider).owlCarousel({
        items: amount,
        lazyLoad:true,
        loop: true,
        margin: 15,
        autoplay: dautoplay,
        autoHeight: true,
        nav: tnav,
        dots: tdots,
        fluidSpeed: 1,
        responsiveClass: true
    });

$( ".owl-prev").html('');
$( ".owl-next").html('');
```

**Edit:**
A Tip i might have, atleast Layout Shifting can be eleminated trough setting the Slider visible in min-height with Styles.
It does not solve the defer Problem but at least the user see's no shifting and it gives a few bonus points.

With Cache-TTL and eliminating Layout Shifting i could get a score of 96 without using defer.

I wish i could but atleast i reached my goal. Should i clouse the question @mods?